# Java String parsing and summing

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am looking to parse an input `String`, and as I am doing it I want to check the number of occurrences of each word while removing all non alphabetic characters.

For example:

```
String str = "test man `xy KA XY test!.. KA kA TeST man poqw``e TES`T"
String s = line.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\ ]", "");
String[] werd = alphaLine.split(" ");

for(int i=0; i<werd.size(); i++) {
     if(werd[i].toLowerCase().equals("test")) {
         testcounter++;
     elseif(werd[i].toLowerCase().equals("ka")) {
         kacounter++;
     etc..
```

I will be checking very long `String`s, and will be checking against many target `String`s (`ka` and `test` in this example), and was trying to see if I could execute this code in one pass through, as right now it seems that for `.replaceAll()`, `.split()`, and then the for loop I am going through all of the `String`s 3 times, when it could be done once.

Comment: I wouldn't be afraid of three loops. Look into `StreamTokenizer`s, though.

Comment: There are good data structures for the purpose, with well tested implementations, such as: http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm on the same page, but it sounds like you're asking how to reduce the number of lookups while searching for words. This may not be the best approach if you have a very large number of search words, but should give the number of occurrences of each word for smaller list.

```
Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("foo");
words.add("bar");

//build regex - note: if this is done within an outer loop, then you should consider using StringBuilder instead
//The \b in regex is a word boundary
String regex = "\\b(";
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    //add word to regex
    regex += (0 == i ? "" : "|") + words.get(i);

    //initial occurrences
    occurrences.add(words.get(i), 0);
}
regex += ")\\b";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(search_string);

//check for matches
while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group();
    int numOccurs = occurrences.get(key) + 1;
    occurrences.put(key, numOccurs);
}
```

EDIT: This is assuming you take care of the non-alphanum requirement before this point